# How do I do a simple Perl hash equivalence comparison?

Tags: perl, hash, comparison

I'm wondering if there's an idiomatic one-liner or a standard-distribution package/function that I can use to compare two Perl hashes with only builtin, non-blessed types. The hashes are not identical (they don't have equivalent memory addresses).

I'd like to know the answer for both for shallow hashes and hashes with nested collections, but I understand that shallow hashes may have a much simpler solution.

TIA!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like cmp_deeply available in [Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Deep) ?

Comment: Sure, I think Test::Deep::eq_deeply is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 4):

[This was a response to an answer by someone who deleted their answer.]

Uh oh!

```
%a ~~ %b && [sort values %a] ~~ [sort values %b]
```

doesn't check whether the values belong to the same keys.

```
#! perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %a = (eat => "banana", say => "whu whu"); # monkey
my %b = (eat => "whu whu", say => "banana"); # gorilla
print "Magilla Gorilla is always right\n" 
    if %a ~~ %b && [sort values %a] ~~ [sort values %b];
```

Comment: ’Tis indeed a courageous Perl programmer of epic proportion who dares to use the smarty-pants `~~` operator. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an easy way or a built-in package, and I don't know what happens when you just do `%hash1 == %hash2` (but that's probably not it), but it's not terribly hard to roll your own:

```
sub hash_comp (\%\%) {
  my %hash1 = %{ shift };
  my %hash2 = %{ shift };
  foreach (keys %hash1) {
    return 1 unless defined $hash2{$_} and $hash1{$_} == $hash2{$_};
    delete $hash1{$_};
    delete $hash2{$_};
  }
  return 1 if keys $hash2;
  return 0;
}
```

Untested, but should return 0 if the hashes have all the same elements and all the same values. This function will have to be modified to account for multidimensional hashes.

If you want something from a standard distribution, you could `use Data::Dumper;` and just dump the two hashes into two scalar variables, then compare the strings for equality. That might work.

There's also a package on CPAN called `FreezeThaw` that looks like it does what you want.

Note that to use the smart match (not repeated here because it's already posted), you will have to `use feature;` and it's only available for Perl 5.10. But who's still using Perl 5.8.8, right?

Comment: Also the "==" comparison forces a scalar context, so it compares number of elements.

Comment: @cdleary: I said that because, as a user of Mac OS X, all OS X users are by default still using 5.8.8, unless they went out of their way to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.

I used Test::More::eq_hash as result.

Answer (score 0):

For shallow hashes:

```
(grep {exists %hash2{$_}} keys %hash1) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

hashes can be casted into arrays, where every value follows its key (but you won't know the order of the keys).  So:

```
( join("",sort(%hash1)) eq join("",sort(%hash2)) )
```

Oh, wait, that won't work because there are some edge cases, like:

```
%hash1 = { 'aaa' => 'aa'  };
%hash2 = { 'aa'  => 'aaa' };
```

So it's best to use a character in the join() that you KNOW will never appear in any key or value.  If the values are BLOBs, that will be a big problem, but for anything else you could use the NULL char "\0".

```
( join("\0",sort(%hash1)) eq join("\0",sort(%hash2)) )
```

Looks kinda ugly, I know, but it will do for checking if two hashes are equal in a shallow way, which is what most people are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eq_deeply](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep#ok-eq_deeply-got-expected) in [Test::Deep::NoTest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep::NoTest). It just returns a boolean that you can check, without the extra overhead of the testing capabilities of the [main module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep).

Answer (score -1):

convert hashes to xml files and compare, and yes you could use multilevel.

```
sub isEqualHash 
{
    my ($self,$hash1, $hash2) = @_;
    my  $file1 = "c:/neo-file1.txt";
    my  $file2 = "c:/neo-file2.txt";
    my $xmlObj = XML::Simple->new();
    my $dummy_file = $xmlObj->XMLout($hash1,OutputFile => $file1);
    my $dummy_file = $xmlObj->XMLout($hash2,OutputFile => $file2);

    open FILE, "<".$file1;
    my $file_contents1 = do { local $/; <FILE> };
    close(FILE);

    open FILE, "<".$file2;
    my $file_contents2 = do { local $/; <FILE> };
    close(FILE);

    if($file_contents1 eq $file_contents2)
    {
        return "Passed";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```