# how to compare two multilevels hashes in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to compare two complex hash structures. In the end, I would like to create an excel report detailing the differences.

Any existing coding that does this?

regards,
Gordon

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540229/how-do-i-do-a-simple-perl-hash-equivalence-comparison and http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=121559

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Data::Compare`](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Data-Compare-1.22/lib/Data/Compare.pm) is your friend. And [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) for report

Comment: i looked at the data::compare, it only returns 1 or 0 which is not enough

Comment: Hash::Diff seems to be a better bet, as long as your structure isn't recursive / self-referential or containing array refs.

Comment: I used recursive hash parser, to determine common parts.